# ksh:Linux - Command to find a particular directory/file

Tags: linux

In a java code I could see some folder structure like 
com.oracle.semisal.abc

com.oracle.semisal.abc is like com/oracle/semisal/abc - where abc is the file name

but no idea where this path is in the server.

kindly provide me a command or script in ksh.

Comment: Can you run the code and then see what files (e.g. with `strace` or `sysdig` or such) the code attempts to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you are having some Java code, where you are seeing the structure `com.oracle.semisal.abc`. That is not a file, neither a directory, that is a reference to another Java code, which may itself be a file.

But you are in the right path. Java artifacts, `.jar`s, have a well-formed structure, and the artifct may include the external code in it. If you are having a `.jar` file, you could look for it with a package inspecting tool, a decompression tool or even with the `jar` tool itself: `jar -xf example.jar`.

So, my best best is:

1. Open/extract your code artifact
2. Examine it for a folder like `com`, which may include a folder called `oracle` and so on
3. Be happy if you found what you were looking for :)
4. (or else, go checking the other artifacts in project. It may include external `.jar` files, which may have what you are looking for)

Comment: Yes I am also thinking the same , because I already search such path in the directories, but there is no such combination.. Thanks.. hegez

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how Java works, I'll narrow this down to just answering the more generic question of how to find a certain path on the system.

If you'd like to locate the path `com/oracle/semisal/abc` anywhere in the filesystem you may try two approaches:

1. `locate abc | grep -F 'com/oracle/semisal/abc'`

   This basically uses the `locate` database to find everything on the filesystem called `abc`.  You then `grep` for the specific path in that output.
2. `find / -path '*/com/oracle/semisal/abc/*' -print`

   This uses `find` to locate all files and directories with `com/oracle/semisal/abc` anywhere in their path.  This will take longer to run and will produce more output (if the path exists at all), but will work if the path is not located where the `locate` command is able to find it (`locate` only looks at things accessible by all users).