# Is it possible to search for a directory/file combination?

Tags: find

I need to find an image, say ABC.jpg, that I know will have been programmatically placed into a directory named ABC_MPSC. I've tried:

```
cd /
find . -name "ABC_MPSC/ABC.jpg"
```

But that doesn't return anything (I actually know where the particular one I'm searching for is, so I know it exists). Is there a find command that could allow me not have to search manually?

Comment: Very similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342392/117549; also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352844/117549

Comment: You can also find it using `locate`, which should be significantly faster, but only works if the file already existed when `updatedb` was last run.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a `-path` predicate that's useful here:

```
find . -path '*/ABC_MPSC/ABC.jpg'
```

The [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) [description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) for that predicate is:

> The primary shall evaluate as true if the current pathname matches pattern using the pattern matching notation described in Pattern Matching Notation. The additional rules in Patterns Used for Filename Expansion do not apply as this is a matching operation, not an expansion.

The reason that your `-name "ABC_MPSC/ABC.jpg"` failed is because the `-name` predicate:

> shall evaluate as true if the basename of the current pathname matches pattern

In other words, `-name` never sees the *directory* of the current filename, only the base filename itself (ABC.jpg, for example).

Answer (score 10):

Two ways (apart from [using `-path`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509491/116858)):

1. Look for the directory, then detect the file:

   ```
   find / -type d -name 'ABC_MPSC' -exec test -f {}/ABC.jpg \; -print
   ```

   This relies on the `find` implementation to expand `{}` to the current pathname of the found directory, even though it's concatenated with `/ABC.jpg` (it's not *required* to do that). It could also be written as

   ```
   find / -type d -name 'ABC_MPSC' \
       -exec sh -c 'test -f "$1"/ABC.jpg' sh {} \; -print
   ```
2. Look for the file, then check it's parent directory name:

   ```
   find / -type f -name 'ABC.jpg' -exec sh -c '
       case $(dirname "$1") in
           */ABC_MPSC) exit 0 ;;
           *) exit 1
       esac' sh {} \; -print
   ```

Both of these alternatives would be slower than using `-path` in the way as Jeff shows. I'm leaving them here as examples none the less, as they could possibly be adapted for other things.